# Passing pointer to function expecting reference changes the value pointed

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, bind

I have following code example. I am passing the pointer to a function. When I pass the pointer to the function it seems the function initializes the argument to some random number. But, when I pass the address of the variable to the function it gives expected result.

```
// find_if example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::find_if
#include <vector>       // std::vector

class A 
{
public:

A(int i) { num = i; }

bool IsPresent (A& a) {
  std::cout << "Comparing " << num << " vs " << a.num << '\n';
  return (num == a.num);
};

int num;
};

int main () {
  std::vector<A*> myvector;

  A a1(10);
  A a2(20);
  A a3(30);
  A a4(40);

  A a(40);
  const A *pa = &a;

  std::cout << "pa is " << pa << '\n';

  myvector.push_back(&a1);
  myvector.push_back(&a2);
  myvector.push_back(&a3);
  myvector.push_back(&a4);

  std::vector<A*>::iterator it = std::find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
                                                                  std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun(&A::IsPresent), pa));
  if (it != myvector.end())
      std::cout << "The first equal value is " << (*it)->num << '\n';
  else
      std::cout << "Cannot find a match";

  return 0;
}
```

1. Why the function  `bool IsPresent (A& a)` initializes the variable `(A& a)` to random value when the parameter is passed by pointer and works when I pass reference of it?

When passed as pointer the result is

```
pa is 0x7b10b4d52e80
Comparing 10 vs -1261097344
Comparing 20 vs -1261097344
Comparing 30 vs -1261097344
Comparing 40 vs -1261097344
Cannot find a match
```

When Passed as reference:

```
pa is 0x75002e9dbb30
Comparing 10 vs 40
Comparing 20 vs 40
Comparing 30 vs 40
Comparing 40 vs 40
The first equal value is 40
```

2. And why the code compiles in first place? The function I am calling expects a reference and I am passing a pointer. Shouldn't the compiler give a warning/error as function not found?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What?  no.  It is either a type error, or not.  No UB from passing typed valid arguments to a typed function signature.  Or is bind 2nd insane?

Comment: Three questions: Where is the boost usage?  Are you using pre-C++11 bind code for a reason?  And what compiler are you using?

Comment: This is an old code. I am not sure why the dev that time did not use boost.  GCC complier, pre C++11.

Comment: What compiler is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::bind2nd` is really poorly designed.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12)

```
template< class F, class T >
std::binder2nd<F> bind2nd( const F& f, const T& x )
```

evaluates to:

```
std::binder2nd<F>(f, typename F::second_argument_type(x))
```

and yes, that is a C-style cast.

We end up with doing an `(A&)(pa)`, which becomes `reinterpret_cast<A&>(pa)`.

Which reinterprets the memory of the pointer to `A` as an instance of `A`.

Did I say that `bind2nd` was poorly designed?  I meant it.

C++11 brings lambdas and `std::bind`, both of which are head and shoulders and body and feet and foundation and planet above `bind2nd` and `bind1st`.

There is a reason why `std::bind2nd` is deprecated and removed from the standard.  This is only **part** of the reason (also because it relies on its function arguments telling it what the argument types are, which `std::bind` does not).

---

`std::mem_fun` is also deprecated and removed from the standard, but it does nothing wrong here.  Still, replace it with `std::mem_fn` which does the same job but better as a first step.

---

Your code will fail to compile if you blindly replace `std::mem_fun` with `std::mem_fn` and `std::bind2nd` with `std::bind( first_arg, std::_1, second_arg )` unless `second_arg` matches the right type.  It will do so in a spew of template spam.

Better is:

```
std::vector<A*>::iterator it = std::find_if (
  myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
  [pa](A* a){ a->IsPresent(*pa); }
);
```

which if you forget to dereference `pa` generates a really simple and easy to read compiler error message.

Answer (score 0):

**Why the function  bool IsPresent (A& a) initializes the variable (A& a) to random value when the parameter is passed by pointer and works when I pass reference of it?**

The "A& a" parameter is defined as a reference variable, when you pass the pointer object, it is trying to interpret the object as a reference. The correct way is pass its content.

*In order to improve your solution, you can define isPresent as bool isPresent(const A& a)*

**And why the code compiles in first place? The function I am calling expects a reference and I am passing a pointer. Shouldn't the compiler give a warning/error as function not found?**

It can be interpreted wrongly as a reference. As a result it compile correctly but the execution fails.

Comment: Same issue even when I use isPresent(const A& a). Moreover even if it is const 'a' is initialized to random value

Comment: The improvement of const is to avoid the modification of the reference